# Is it bad practice to implement a separate table consisting of only two rows Female and Male?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-design

Assume we have a `Person` table with 3 columns:

1. `PersonId` of type `int`. (Primary key)
2. `Name` of type `string`.
3. `GenderId` of type `int` (Foreign key referencing `Gender` table).

The `Gender` table consists of 2 columns:

1. `GenderId` of type `int`.
2. `Name` of type `string`.

My question is:
Is it worth implementing the `Gender` table? Or it causes performance degradation? What is the best way to handle this?

### Edit 1:

I have to populate a drop down control with a list of fixed genders (female and male) in my UI.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't make Gender a column in the Person table?

Comment: @shrodes - His proposed approach is more normalized, which is a noble cause. Why store the string "Male" or "Female" in the db thousands of times when there are only two different values? The question is if this is pragmatically a good idea.

Comment: @Greg yeah, i agree it is a noble cause, i also think in this case it's unnecessary normalization

Comment: @shrodes: The Gender column will be populated by selecting an option from a drop down control on the UI later. I do this way to avoid error prone during the manual data entry.

Comment: I'd stick with this. Any performance degradation will be negligible. Don't compromise your data model for the sake of performance. Mind you there are times when you do de-normalize or have a different database entirely using a start scheme or similar for reporting purposes). The way you're doing it also help's in the UI, that is you can use the lookup table to populate dropdowns etc. Of course in most systems I've worked on there are more then 2 items in the gender table. If that happens here, you've good to go. Simply add the others to the look up.

Comment: @user - I recommend adding the detail about using the gender table to populate the UI to your question.

Comment: @Greg, it's called over-normalization. Creating another table for two values is pretty pointless, it should just be an Enum in code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best approach in this case is a compromise:

1. Create a table called Gender with a single varchar column called 'Name' or 'Gender'. Gender is really a natural primary key. Put the values 'Male' and 'Female' in it.
2. Create foreign key to your Person table on a column named 'Gender'.

Now you only need to query from one table, but you're still protected from data inconsistencies by the foreign key, and you can pull the values for your dropdown from the Gender table if you want to. Best of both worlds.

Additionally, it makes life easier for someone working in the database, because they don't need to remember which arbitrary ids you've assigned to Male/Female.

Comment: What about third gender?

Comment: Add another row to your Gender table.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a field with only two possible values, you don't need another table for it. You can just use something like a `BIT` (0=male, 1=female) or a `CHAR` ('M' and 'F').

Comment: Agreed, only you might want to call it IsMale or IsFemale.  The choice of constants is not obvious to all... apparently :)

Comment: @Mark: +1 for `BIT`. But not for `CHAR`.

Comment: Bit is a terrible terrible suggestion. Very unneccessary and unintuitive and also technically incorrect. Wrong on all levels. Hence the downvote from me.

Comment: Although is "gender" really just a bit-field these days?

Comment: @Noon if there are only two values then it is a single __bit__ of information. It would be a different matter if it was strictly a _boolean_.

Comment: @Mark: I don't disagree with that logic. My comment still is applicable though.

Comment: @Mark Cidade is "gender" really just a bit-field these days?

Comment: @Noon Silk, "technically incorrect"? Is this database for people or not? How many genders we have?

Comment: @pst In real life, it's more of a spectrum of sexual traits—what may be reflected in a database schema can be a matter of 2 or 3 options. On Facebook, I can only choose between having a male cousin or a female cousin.

Answer (score 4):

I am firm believe in *lookup-tables* for this -- which is essentially what is being proposed but with one distinction: use *friendly non-auto-generated PKs*.

For instance the PKs might be: "M", "F", "N" (and there might be 2-4 or so rows depending upon accepted gender classifications). Using a simple PK allows easy queries while still allowing a higher form of normalization and referential consistency constraints *without* having to employ check-constraints.

As the question proposes, I also employ additional columns, such as a Name/Title/Label as appropriate (these are useful as a reference and add self-documentation to the *identities*). McCarthy advocates using this data itself as the PK (which is one option), but I consider this a trait *of* the identity and use more terse hand-picked PK.

In this sense, I hold the entire concept of *lookup-tables* to provide the same sort of role as "constants" in code.

Comment: @p.campbell at least we're not discussing how the "sex" should be normalized ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Normalizing gender into a separate table is overkill in this instance.
Why not just have GenderType as a string in the first table?

That way you save having to generate and store an extra GenderID (try to minimise the use of IDs as otherwise all you'll have in a table is a whole lot of columns just pointing to other tables... over normalization)

Comment: Using another table adds referential integrity. The best part is it *can* be a string in the first table and still be enforced within the data-base model -- I prefer a hand-picked surrogate PK (e.g. "M", "F" with *attributes* of "Male" and "Female", respectively) while McCarthy advocated using the full gender title as the PK ("Male", "Female"). Check constraints can also be used, but they require special "reflection" to analyze. Relational databases are *designed* for this sort of thing -- might as well use it as designed.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what other people are saying, you can also create an INDEX ( PersonId, GenderId ) to fasten up the calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you only have two possible genders, and that this is extremely unlikely to need to change in the future, I would not bother to have a separate table. Just add a column to your Person table. A join can be efficient if needed, but it is always slower than no join.

And if, for whatever reason, you feel the need for more than two possible genders, you can still store them in a single column in the Person table.

Comment: Are you sure there are only two possible genders that a person or patient would self-identify?

Comment: I can certainly imagine limiting it to two choices.

Comment: [this](http://meteor.aihw.gov.au/content/index.phtml/itemId/287316) standard has 4 choices... but as you suggest, should still be stored in a column in the Person table.

Comment: @sasfrog: LOL, no thanks. Unless I'm working for a client who feels compelled to delve embrace that sort of PC crap, my own projects will limit it to two choices. Why the downvote?